# Can not login with GAPI (Google Analaytic API) from another server

Tags: google-api

I have problem to login with GAPI for retrieve analytic data.

I run GAPI from my localhost was working well. But when I run GAPi from another server I failed login

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Authorization/Authentication flow ahead of your extraction process, you might have to make some changes to your acceptable "Redirect URIs"

It would helpful if you add some details to your questions.